# Create customer wise google analytics

Tags: customer, customer-account, google-analytics

I am new for Google Analytics.I have read about this.But I can not get solution of my query.

Please help me on that.

My query is, suppose I have 3 customers on my store and they can upload their products from their own dashboard.Now I want to display a graph/chart on these 3 customer's dashboard for visitors who visits that particular customer's product.

So how can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Going for google analytic you can create a custom plugin ,

Use the below collections to get data and add filter to that collection where product ids are related to that user

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-most-viewed-products/

Comment: Ok,But If I want to show this traffic on dashboard as graph then ?

Comment: Magento Dashboard ?

Comment: I am talking about dashboard of customer.